# Magento installation webpage not available error

Tags: magento, installation

I am new to Magento and installing it.

While installation i have put in /www folder. So when i access url in browser like **localhost/magento** it shows webpage not available though i have followed every step as per the guideline

Comment: provide more information to prevent downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `/www` folder your webserver's root? To me it seems that when you type `localhost/magento`, the installation needs to be in the magento folder on your server.

Comment: Actually i am drupal developer and learning magento. As far as any cms is concerned there is same method for installation, put in www folder and install it

Comment: How did you install it, by calling the install.php script?

Comment: i also tried to call using install.php but not working yet. Is there any thing like that i have to install sample data ?

Comment: No, the shop will work without sample data, this is not part of the problem. Can you post your paths on the server? This might help.